# GitHub API - latest public repositories

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to list public GitHub repositories with the latest create/update/push timestamps (for me any of these is acceptable). Can I achieve this with the GitHub API?

I have tried the following:

1. Tried using `/repositories` endpoint, and use the link header to navigate to the last page. However, the link header I receive only has `first` and `next` links, whereas I need a `last` link.
2. Tried using `/search/repositories` endpoint. This will work as long as I have a keyword or filter in the `q` parameter, but it will not accept an empty `q` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I got in touch with GitHub support, and there are two solutions to this:

1. Use binary search on the `since` parameter of the `/repositories` endpoint to find the last page.
   Cons: may quickly exhaust the API rate limit.
2. Use the `/search/repositories` endpoint with an always-true predicate such as `stars>=0`.
   Cons: likely to cause a query timeout/ incomplete results.

Comment: Can you explain the first solution more in detail ?